# Firebase not allowing Facebook login

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting a weird internal error on Firebase when I'm trying to login to Facebook:

> "FIRAuthErrorDomain" - code: 17999

App works just fine when trying to log in using Anonymous auth. I tried re-downloading the `GoogleService-Info.plist`, deleting the app from Firebase, enabling the Identity Toolkit API and hardcoding a Facebook token with no success.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok! Fixed

So I found that I was retrieving the FB token from the wrong App Id - which didn't have the redirect URI set up.